# Export a Obj with a wireframe material

Tags: export, wireframe

I would like to export an obj with a wireframe material (model with wireframe lines). I don't want to render it as an image and I don't want to use the wireframe modifier. The Modifier would be the look I am aiming for, only the model gets very large in file size by doing that. It seemed to be a trivial thing, but it turned out to take longer than I thought. Ideally in step two I would like to color the wireframe.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541